# How to remove the yellow row highlighting

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in an application, and I want to use my own styling for it. The first step is that I want to remove the yellow highlighting that the jqGrid css has when I click on a row. I tried to find it but had no success. If anyone knows how to switch the highlighting off please let me know. Also please mention in which css file I have to make the change in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best solution would be at add this code to your jqGrid parameters rather than changing the css

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    return false;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the following CSS statement **after** loading your `jquery.ui.css` to override style:

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight
{
    border: 1px solid red !important; // Desirable border color
    background: none !important; // Desirable background color
    color: black !important; // Desirable text color
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Remove the comments. For a moment only the border was being picked up and it drove me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this css in the jquery-ui.css file. It's the `ui-state-highlight` class you need to modify. Good luck.

Comment: Should probably override any changes in a CSS file that's loaded after the jquery-ui css file. This will allow you to upgrade jquery ui if you need to and still maintain that change (if the class name doesn't change down the road or anything like that)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two classes with names "holdRow" for blue background and "HighlightHoldRow" for yellow color background then By using the below code "RowSelect" is the method which is invoked during row select,

Consider the following code

```
   .holdRow td {
font-weight : bold !important;
color: Blue !important;
  }

   .higLightholdRow td {
font-weight : bold !important;
color: Yellow !important;
```

}

```
   var LastRowId = "";
    function RowSelect(id) {
if (Flag == "TRUE") {
    var grid = $('#gvName);
    if (LastRowId != "" && LastRowId != undefined && LastRowId != id) {
        tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(LastRowId);
        $(tr).removeClass("higLightholdRow");
        $(tr).addClass("holdRow");
        LastRowId = "";
    }
    tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(id);
    $(tr).removeClass("holdRow");
    $(tr).addClass("higLightholdRow");
    LastRowId = id;

}
```

}

```
   ClientSideEvents-RowSelect="RowSelect"
```

The RowSelect method is invoked during the selection of a row,and selected row will have yellow color as background and remaining rows will have blue color as background